# How to copy items from list to stack without using loop

Tags: c#, list, stack

I do have a Stack and a List. I need to copy all the items from list to stack without using loops i.e for, foreach.. etc.

Is there recommended way of doing it?

Comment: Why do you **need** to do it without using any loops?

Comment: in java you can do this by { List b = new ArrayList(a);
Collections.copy(b,a);}

Comment: This sounds like either homework or an interview question... which is it?!

Comment: is goto considered a loop? :)

Comment: @fsonmezay: You can also do that in C#, but it still uses a loop. It's just hidden inside `copy`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can create a stack from anything that is IEnumerable

```
var myStack = new Stack<MyObjectType>(myList);
```

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68.aspx

However, the stack constructor will be using a loop internally, you just don't see it.

Comment: And myStack will Pop the myList items in reverse order. You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to Pop the items in the same order as they appear in your list,
then reverse your list before you create the stack from it.

```
var myStack = new Stack<MyObjectType>(myList.Reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Stack<T>(myListOfT)
```

Alternatively (without loops)

```
myStack.Push(myList[0]);
myStack.Push(myList[1]);
myStack.Push(myList[2]);
myStack.Push(myList[3]);
...
```

It's going to get pretty tedious. What's wrong with loops?

Answer (score -1):

In java 1.8 Stack has a predefined method call addAll - Item will be push on to the stack

stack.addAll(list);